# Adding duplicate data into one entry

Tags: python, dataframe, series

I have a multi-index on my data for the borough, year and month for which murders were recorded. I am trying to organise my dataframe such that there is a multi-index for rows, being borough and Year and then having the column data as the months.

My problem is that as is currently arranged, there are duplicate values in the month column as individual murders are recorded. So for example, in a given area in 2008, there may be 3 entries for march as three separate murders occurred here.[image: Pic of my dataframe]

What I want to achieve is having a multi-index dataframe with borough and year as the indexes and the months as the columns heads and the corresponding values as the values. How can I sum the values of the value column so the total value for a given month would be all murders carried out in this month for example, in 2016 september how do I have one entry for september with a value of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try groupby:

```
df['value'].groupby(['borough', 'year', 'month']).sum()
```